# Можно ли в yandex-картах пронумеровать свои маркеры?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте.
Можно ли в yandex-картах пронумеровать свои маркеры?

Answer (score 1):

Можно. А также можно менять и вид самого маркера. Почитайте в руководстве для разработчиков. Нужно использовать кластеризацию. На [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/207202/) это описано.

Comment: @kamila, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: Исправляюсь)

Comment: В этой статье говориться о том, как объединить много маркеров в один кластер. А мне нужно у каждого маркера задать номер.
В документации написано, что существуют метки с текстом, куда можно вставлять свой текст, используя
iconContent: 'Hello world!'
На остальные типы маркеров текст таким образом не добавляется, в том числе и на мой собственный маркер.